# Selenium Auto Submits Form with Send_keys?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using `Selenium 2.53` with `python 3.4` and `firefox 47` to do automation testing. When using `.send_keys` (sendKeys in Java) it will auto submit the form when I dont want it to.

The form input that I'm sending keys to is:

```
<input tabindex="1" type="text"
                    name="PostingTitle"
                    id="PostingTitle"
                    maxlength="70"
            </label>
```

It's strange because it doesnt do this with all the forms. Is there a way to tell selenium not to submit?

Comment: What string are you sending with "send keys"? Any chance there is a newline there?

Comment: Could you share sending string as well using `send_keys()`?? Are you sending enter key or other?? Or is there any event occurs during sendKeys on this HTML??

Comment: Thanks for the response. No new line and no 'enter' or 'return' or related keys.

Comment: No event occuring during sendKeys on the html.

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to say why sendKeys submit your form, you can use `execute_script()` which would silently set the value into your textbox as `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]",driver.find_element_by_id("PostingTitle"),"your value to set")` and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using .send_keys (sendKeys in Java) it will auto submit the form when I dont want it to.

It might be possible your desired text box is capturing key events during sendKeys which may be call any JavaScript function to submit the form, because `sendKeys` working normally as user input from keys.

From comments :-

> No new line and no 'enter' or 'return' or related keys.
>   No event occuring during sendKeys on the html.

Then it's hard to say why `sendKeys` submit your form.

You can use `execute_script()` instead which would silently set the value into your textbox without occuring any events as :-

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", driver.find_element_by_id("PostingTitle"), "you‌​r value to set")
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!